# Virto Commerce: frontend not working

Tags: virtocommerce

I have a fully functional 'platform' (test) solution, both locally and on azure, but I have troubles to setup a working 'storefront' solution, first locally! I followed all the steps within documentation, but I have no "\App_Data\cms-content\" path mentioned within ContentConnectionString storefront setting in Web.config. My storefront website correctly connects to the default store but some exceptions throw during debug; I have some category and product in default store catalog, but nothing of these appear (see attached images): where I wrong?

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJz89.png)

[Homepage with errors and no products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp3WR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Look to the platform 'App_data' directory. Point is that storefront and platform should share the same CMS content location. So just use default path of the platform. Set *ContentConnectionString* to full path of platform "\App_Data\cms-content\" in storefront. For example:

```
<add name="ContentConnectionString" connectionString="provider=LocalStorage;rootPath=C:\vc-platform-master\VirtoCommerce.Platform.Web\App_Data\cms-content" />
```

Comment: To facilitate a shared location you can use AzureBlobStorage. Locally I run the Storefront right out of Visual Studio with a connection to a "dev" instance of the platform running in Azure. The AzureBlobStorage is then shared between them. 

Change the ConnectionStrings named VirtoCommerceBaseUrl and ContentConnectionString.